# class not found in Actionscript error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flash, mxml

I am trying to run the program from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7ff4.html

I am using Adbobe builder version 4.6 i encounter this problem WAVwriter class not found
when i do import com.adobe.audio.format.WAVWriter;

Also var outputFile:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("recording.wav");  File type is not found..

How to resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**File** is an AIR class, make sure your project is for desktop or mobile (AIR). If not, you can make new desktop project by going to **File/New/Flex Project...** and check in the **Desktop** checkbox (for mobile, choose **Flex Mobile Project**).

Regarding **WAVWriter**, make sure you linked the related sources.

Comment: Does that mean that the application cannot be run on a web browser

Comment: That's right, you cannot manipulate the user filesystem from the browser (it is not Flex limitation but browser limitation in order to protect user computer). If you want to use a file from the local filesystem, you can do it only if user clicks and select this file manually using **FileReference.browse()**.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as Adnan Doric said. And if you want to output your file using Flash Player runtime (instead of AIR), you should use **flash.net.FileReference** class. Calling its dowload() method will pop up an external dialog which can be used to save your file.